# Associations with combination foreign key in Sails.js/Waterline

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I need to have a model called 'Package' which can have one or more children of several different types. For example, a package can contain guides, as well as forms and other content types (some of which will be added later). Each of these content items, from different tables, can be in multiple packages. So I have the following schema:

```
Package table
=============
id
name
....

PackageContent table
=============
id
packageId
contentType
contentId

Guide table
=============
id
name
...

Form table
=============
id
name
```

How can I define the 'content' association for my packages in my Package.js model file in sails.js? I have not been able to find any information on combination foreign keys in sails.js or Waterline. I would hope to find something along the lines of:

```
// models/Package.js
module.exports = {
  attributes = {
    name: 'text',

    ....

    content: {
      through: 'PackageContent',
      collection: contentType,
      via: 'contentId'
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem recently. My solution is to create different foreign keys in the intermediary model and set attributes as 'required:false'. In your example, the PackageContent table could look like this:

```
 //PackageContent.js
 module.exports={
    attributes={
        package:{
            model:'package',
        },
        guide:{
            model:'guide'
            require:false
        },
        form:{
            model:'form'
            require:false
        }
        //other attributes...
    }
}
```

In order to avoid duplicated package+content combination, you may need to write a beforeValidate method to check the duplication. I am not sure if this is a 'good design', but it solves the probelm

Comment: This is a good start, as you mentioned it needs some extra filtering.